# Google Analytics in Ionic Mobile Apps

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework, google-analytics-api, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing Ionic mobile app and I'd like to integrate Google Analytics in my app. I see Google Analytics has native SDK's for Native mobile apps and Web Tracking js for web apps. I want to know which is the best method to integrate GA in my Ionic app?

1. Use Native SDK's and create custom Cordova plugins to talk to them for each platform I support?
2. Use Web Api and intercept each request from Native code and use Native SDK's to track the request? (Combination of Web Api and Native SDK's)
3. Use some third party Cordova plugin from Git? (May stop supporting future releases of GA or Cordova)

I'd want to know which is the recommended option for me right now? Any piece of advice is appreciated :)